# How can I install Moodle with DDEV?

Tags: docker, moodle, ddev

I was trying to install Moodle LMS using ddev.

-- The problem is that Moodle requires mariadb 10.6, whilst ddev only supports mariadb 10.4.

Steps tried:

1. change the .ddev/config.ph docker file from 10.4 to 10.6 <-- didn't work.
2. when given the install page in Moodle - it complaining about Moodle not meetings its requirements.
3. DDEV has instruction on their site - for such an install. But, I suspect its out o date.
4. I tried deleting the docker image mariadb10.4, hoping it would upgrade - no luck.
5. the ddev exec below: will not work at all.
6. should I try podman instead?

any ideas or suggestions.

thank
Carlo

```
ddev config --composer-root=public --create-docroot --docroot=public --webserver-type=apache-fpm
ddev start
ddev composer create moodle/moodle -y
ddev exec 'php public/admin/cli/install.php --non-interactive --agree-license --wwwroot=$DDEV_PRIMARY_URL --dbtype=mariadb --dbhost=db --dbname=db --dbuser=db --dbpass=db --fullname="DDEV Moodle Demo" --shortname=Demo --adminpass=password'
ddev launch /login
```

I tried everything I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

DDEV supports many, many MariaDB versions, including 10.8 and 10.11.

You'll find the [quickstart for Moodle](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/configuration/config/#database) in the DDEV docs.

```
ddev config --composer-root=public --create-docroot --docroot=public --webserver-type=apache-fpm
ddev start
ddev composer create moodle/moodle -y
ddev exec 'php public/admin/cli/install.php --non-interactive --agree-license --wwwroot=$DDEV_PRIMARY_URL --dbtype=mariadb --dbhost=db --dbname=db --dbuser=db --dbpass=db --fullname="DDEV Moodle Demo" --shortname=Demo --adminpass=password'
ddev launch /login
```

I do see that the DDEV quickstart doesn't have the [updated database requirement](https://download.moodle.org/releases/latest/), but you can fix that with `ddev config --database=mariadb:10.6`

(The [Moodle quickstart](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#moodle) has been updated to show mariadb 10.6.)

Comment: Docs PR: https://github.com/ddev/ddev/pull/5252